# Поднять "Рекламу" вместе с SnackBar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toast

Необходимо, чтоб SnackBar при появлении поднимал находящийся над ним Рекламный блок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cordinatorSavedList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvLists"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Код вызова:

```
CoordinatorLayout cordinatorSavedList = (CoordinatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.cordinatorSavedList);
Snackbar.make(cordinatorSavedList, "Удалить список?", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для вашего AdView достаточно добавить в разметке:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
ads:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"
```

Из документации:
dodgeInsetEdges - A Gravity value describing how this child view dodges any inset child views in the CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!:) Я варианты с использованием спец классов пытался применить, а тут буквально одна строчка кода все сделала:)

Comment: обычно для View в CoordinatorLayout пишут кастомный класс Behavior, но такое простое изменение позиции есть в дефолтном